# R Shiny make two inputs equal

Tags: r, shiny

I want to somehow make two inputs equal to one another when I press an Actionbutton. I have several tabs in my Shiny Dashboard and in some of the tabs there are repeat data inputs. For example, in tab 1 we have an input for AGE, we have the same input in tab 2. I want to make it such that if I input a value for age and click "run" (an Actionbutton), then it automatically makes the age in the other tab equal to the one in the current tab.

I'm really really new to using Shiny, so I made a few attempts at using reactive commands, but I'm not sure why it isn't working:

```
  reactive(  
if(input$runbutton==0){
input$numeric1=input$numeric2
})
```

That code has no effect, it doesn't even return an error.

Comment: How about trying `updateNumericInput()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `updateNumericInput()` to change the value of an input. Also it makes more sense to use `observeEvent()` to track button presses. Here a simple sample application

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    numericInput("numeric1","in1",1), 
    numericInput("numeric2","in2",2), 
    actionButton("runbutton", "set equal")
 )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(  input$runbutton, {
        updateNumericInput(session, "numeric1", value=input$numeric2)
    })
}


shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: It works beautifully! Thank you so much! I can see how we need to deal with these kind of issues now; but I was wondering two things if that's alright. Firstly, why exactly do we use "session"? I looked into it, but I can't find anything that really tells me what it does. Also, what is the difference between 'reactive' and 'observeEvent'? It seems like they do the same kind of thing, but observeEvent is the only one that makes sense to me haha

Comment: We have to use session because `updateNumericInput` requires it. Not much more too it than that. If you are new to Shiny want to get a better understanding of `reactive` and `observeEvent` is would probably be better to check out [these training videos](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/shiny-developer-conference/). It's a big topic that can't really be addressed in a comment.